# Installing pycurl on Windows, DLL error

Tags: python, windows, pycurl

I installed `pycurl` on my Windows 7 64-bit machine with Python 2.7 from the binaries available at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycurl

However, I get the following error

```
>>> import pycurl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

If I run `pip install pycurl`, I get

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycurl in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

So I believe it has installed correctly, but am I missing a DLL file?

Please advise.

Comment: Thanks Games, I would if I could. Unfortutately, I need to run [ebaysdk](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python) and pycurl is a dependancy.

Comment: Did you restart IDLE? If that dsnt work, restart PC?

Comment: tried that, same error `DLL load failed`

Comment: Then you have to compile this yourself.

Comment: Wow, Dependency Walker gave me a long list of missing DLL files. Many existed in my Path, but python isn't recognizing them. It doesn't seem right that I should have to mess with this - it'll likely lead to more problems down the road. I'm going to rewrite the ebaysdk to use urllib2 instead of pycurl.

Comment: @tomcounsell:  Have you manage to install pycurl ? I am in same situation, i got the same error "ImportError: DLL load failed:". I wonder how you get rid off this problem ?

Comment: sorry @Khokhar. The simplest solution is often the best. In this case, it was **don't use pycurl**.

Answer (score 2):

Hi，I was in same situation, I got the same error "ImportError: DLL load failed:". Eventually, I solved it simply by update my python from 2.7.2 to 2.7.6 when I noticed that the intaller is built for python 2.7.6.
However, my os is Windows 7 32-bit. I hope my solution can help you. Good luck.

Comment: Wow, thanks.  That fixed mine too!  Any idea what's wrong with the original 2.7 release?